# ModeBuilder doesnt contain UseSerialColumns (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,NCoreUtils.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilderExtensions installed)

Tags: c#, database

I'm following this video https://youtu.be/yGwGLcqcJ6Q?t=390 at 6.30min.

The code is `modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();`.  The editor complains about this

```
Error   CS1061  'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSerialColumns' and no accessible extension method 'UseSerialColumns' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and  NCoreUtils.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilderExtensions` from NuGet. I check the source provided with the video:

https://github.com/techwithpat/MovieApp/blob/master/MovieApp.Data/MovieDataContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MovieApp.Data
{
    public class MovieDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovieDataContext(DbContextOptions<MovieDataContext> options):
            base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and it does not have this problem.

Why am I getting this error ?

Thanks !

Comment: You've got the wrong library. `UseSerialColumns` is defined here: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions.html#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions_UseSerialColumns_ModelBuilder_

Comment: @Dai .  I have already added using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; but it still complain.

Comment: A `using` statement (i.e. a namespace import) is not the same thing as an assembly or NuGet package reference.

Comment: @Dai I've already added the package in NuGet.   It's not complaining about the package but the UseSerialColumns.

Comment: You've only mentioned adding the `NCoreUtils.Data` package - that's the wrong package.

Comment: @Dai Sorry about it.  I've installed both and UseSerialColumns still flag error.  I've updated the question.  Really sorry about it.

Comment: This is the package you want: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/

Comment: @Dai  I finally got it !!!!  After installing Npgsql for Postgresql, the red underline went away !!!  Thanks very much for your help and bearing with me.  I really appreciate it as I finally could continue.  Happy now !

Comment: ...all you had to do was read the documentation

Comment: @Dai Apologies.  I did try.  But I couldn't get it to work.  Sorry...